# PDF File Edited In Illustrator CS6 Not Saving

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a few pdf files to edit in .ai, some fonts could not be read and so I downloaded the fonts, and then it started to tell me (An unknown error has occured) whenever I try to save the file. It does not matter if I saved it to a different folder or changing the name or reopening ai. I have also deleted the fonts from my font book and the same message still shown.

Comment: I have tried to reset Illustrator with no luck (using command/shift/control/option when opening the application). The same issue exist with the same file.

Comment: I have just tried to reset my font book...and the files could not be opened in ai...then I reopened ai and it read the files again but this time saying the some fonts could not be read message again...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other software running? I used to have this problem occur when running Zune music player at the same time as Illustrator. There may be other programs with the same problem.  A restart (without opening the other program of course) fixes the issue for me.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).